# USB Soundcard Device Class Specification document

Tags: audio, usb

I'm looking for a specific document.

I was reading the 'USB Audio Device Class Specification for Basic
Audio Devices' document (http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/audio10.pdf). In section 1.1 in that document, it is mentioned that "More complex audio devices, such as USB soundcard devices are not part of this specification".

Can someone point me to a document that does have the specification for USB soundcard devices? Do I need to be a member of the USB-IF to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the "Universal Serial Bus Device Class Definition for Audio Devices" which is, ironically, the document you linked to, not the specification for basic devices.

Comment: I apologize for linking to the wrong document. The document I wanted to link to is, of course, in this zip file: http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/BasicAudioDevice-10.zip. 

However, the "Universal Serial Bus Device Class Definition for Audio Devices" document at http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/audio10.pdf does not specifically refer to any examples for USB soundcards - which is what I'm looking for

Comment: It does not provide a specific example however audio10.pdf does provide the specification for how to instruct an arbitrarily complex USB audio interface including multiple inputs, outputs and control elements, i.e. a USB sound card.